# ByteMultiArray publish fails if data > 10 bytes

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have next code:

```
data = file.read()  
arr = ByteMultiArray()  
arr.data = list(bytearray(data))  
arr.layout.dim.append(MultiArrayDimension())  
arr.layout.dim[0].label = "soundfile"  
arr.layout.dim[0].size = len(arr.data)  
arr.layout.dim[0].stride = len(arr.data)  
arr.layout.data_offset = 0  
pub.publish(arr)
```

When data 10 and less publish succeed
When data > 10 I have

```
rospy.exceptions.ROSSerializationException: field data[] exceeds specified width [byte]
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276787/bytemultiarray-publish-fails-if-data-%3E-10-bytes/) by [fpgamcu](https://answers.ros.org/users/32779/fpgamcu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2017-11-27

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [daydreamhippo](https://answers.ros.org/users/123267/daydreamhippo/) on 2023-02-23**:
Yeah! I met the same problem. Did you fixed it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

At first glance the problem looks like the stride value you are giving it. The stride is the number of bytes for each element in the array in this case 1, it definitely shouldn't be the array length. Try setting the stride to 1 and see if that fixes the problem.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2017-11-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fpgamcu](https://answers.ros.org/users/32779/fpgamcu/) on 2017-11-29**:
With stride = 1 still same error.